# Mongorestore is stuck using with MongoDB in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, bson, mongorestore

I have a `.gz` archive that was created by `mongodump --gzip`. I want to restore a database from this archive. I use

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=filename.gz --db db_name
```

and then the process stuck (hasn't finished for two hours) [mongorestore stuck on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE0i1.png)

my MongoDB is running in `docker` and i'm trying to restore it inside the container.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: You did not specify the Authentication Database, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470